What does the phrase "человек с большой буквы" mean?
I was just called a "человек с большой буквы" by a native Russian speaker in a text message and I was wondering, what the phrase actually means and where it originates from. I know that it literally translates to a "person (written) in capital letters", but I suppose its an idiom for something.

This expression is used to describe a person of character, meaning high moral character.
This idiomatic expression was first used by M.Gorky in a obituary-like essay about Lenin published in 1924.  I found it online here: https://sovtime.ru/rulers/lenin/gorky-lenin/

Я бы назвал эту основную черту его характера воинствующим оптимизмом, и это была в нем не русская черта. Именно она особенно привлекала душу мою к этому человеку, — Человеку с большой буквы.

Source: https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/chelovek-s-bolshoy-bukvy-obraz-v-i-lenina-i-ego-metamorfozy-v-tvorchestve-m-gorkogo

Сразу после смерти Ленина, в начале 1924 г. Горький создал свой знаменитый очерк «Владимир Ленин», в котором впервые вождь революции был назван Человеком с большой буквы.

Literally, it means "capitalized", i.e. written with a capital initial letter, like Всевышний Господь Бог, Царь-Президент, or Родина. Note how Gorky wrote "Человек" - with an uppercase first letter, to express respect and admiration.

It means "a person who deserves respect" (for whatever reason, should be clear from context), "someone with admirable human qualities". It actually translates to a "person (written) with a capital letter", i.e. "a Person", not "a PERSON".

Thanks for pointing out that its a (single) capital letter. Got that wrong!

Ordinary words start with lower-case letters if they are not the initial words in a sentence. Proper nouns start with capital letters. In Russian they can be names (personal names or placenames), or words like Бог (God) and Родина (Motherland). An initial capital letter is associated with respect. Furthermore, an initial lower-case letter used in a personal name intentionally is a direct sign of disrespect. Technically you can use a lower-case letter, but only to demonstrate disrespect. So человек с большой буквы means великий человек. It is a normal phrase in Russian.

I've never encountered a personal name being written with a lower-case letter intentionally as a sign of disrespect. Besides people on the Internet being lazy and disrespectful towards language in general, writing everything in lower-case letters, of course.
